# Shortest path routing doesn't work

Tags: qgis, routing

Let's say we have the following line layer. [image]

Why is that when we perform routing, it doesn't go from point A to point B like below:

[image]

Instead, it goes in the other path. I've sent the one way direction to false, yet it still chooses the other longer path. I'm using QGIS

[image]

Comment: I would first check your network connectivity and how the roads are connected.  do they actually share a node or are they laid over each other so the network is interpreting it as two unconnected lines.  Also are you using z values.  Some settings will cause the router to interpret one road as higher and therefore make it a highway with no direct connection to the other road (ie its an overpass instead of an intersection)

Comment: As I see this two lines are not having common node so pg_routing don't know they are joined together. Of course you know that pg_routing requires properly prepared data to work correctly?

Comment: @Jendrusk http://puu.sh/kvLe4/c7122d308e.jpg the two lines have a common node, their x and y coordinates are the same

Comment: If so, then Your road network is incorrect - this lines have to start/end in point of crossing... You can't route via standard line layer - it have to be a topology - more info here: http://workshop.pgrouting.org/ (look at point 4)